# Prevent dimming when starting activity android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When I switch activities in my android app, there is a quick (half a second) dim in the screen, as it renders.

e.g. If I press a button that starts an activity, the screen will quickly dim.

Is there anyway I can stop this???

Many Thanks
Ed

Comment: Put some code of yours

Comment: Make sure your are not blocking UI thread with heavy task before onResume() is called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe if you try to turn off animation you will get what you need

```
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.stay, R.anim.stay)
//then start the new activity
```

R.anim.stay:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
</set>
```

Comment: wow, worked great, I am very impressed you came up with such a clean working solution so quickly! I didnt even know overridependingtransition existed!